# Does Solr have an equivalent to CompassQueryBuilder?

Tags: solr, compass-lucene

I am rewriting our company's search functionality to use Solr instead of Compass. Our old code is using CompassQueryBuilder.CompassQueryStringBuilder to build a query out of a list of keywords. The keywords may have spaces in them: for example: "john smith", "tom jones".

Is there an existing facility I can use in Solr to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr offers a wide variety of querying and indexing options. So fields that contain keywords with spaces in it, can be made possible by defining a custom type in the configuration file (see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPlugins)). Queries with spaced keywords in it can be made possible by specifying a custom QueryParser. (see [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax))

Solr itself doesn't offer a QueryStringBuilder in an API. Actually, Solr itself doesn't offer any API classes at all, since all interaction is done by posting messages over Http. There are client libraries for Java, .NET and PHP etc. In the SolrNet api there exists a SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery, which is quite similar to the CompassQueryStringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I know for SolrJ is the [solrj-criteria](http://code.google.com/p/solrj-criteria/) project. It seems to be currently unmaintained though.